# About re.findall

Tags: python, python-3.x, findall

Below are my python code:

```
import re

msg = '''txt@deepstone.com.tw kkk@gmail.com'''
pattern = r'''(
        [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+     
        @                           
        [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+      
        \.                           
        [a-zA-Z]{2,4}       
        (\.)?                      
        ([a-zA-Z]{2,4})?  
        )'''
email = re.findall(pattern, msg, re.VERBOSE)
print(email)
```

I ran it in the python shell and I got the result below:

```
[('txt@deepstone.com.tw', '', ''), ('kkk@gmail.com', '', '')]
```

My question is why the 2nd and 3rd elements in 1st tuple are empty?
I thought in the 2nd and 3rd elements in the 1st tuple would be "." and "tw".

Do I mis-understand anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first character class after the `@` (`[a-zA-Z0-9-.]`) includes the literal `.` and it is matched greedily, meaning it will go as far as it can instead of stopping as soon as it can.

You can avoid this by either matching it non-greedily (`[...]+?`) or removing the dot, thus allowing the rest of the regexp to match.

Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> msg = '''txt@deepstone.com.tw kkk@gmail.com'''
>>> pattern2 = r'''(
...         [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+
...         @
...         [a-zA-Z0-9-]+
...         \.
...         [a-zA-Z]{2,4}
...         (\.)?
...         ([a-zA-Z]{2,4})?
...         )'''
>>> re.findall(pattern2, msg, re.VERBOSE)
[('txt@deepstone.com.tw', '.', 'tw'), ('kkk@gmail.com', '', '')]
>>> pattern3 = r'''(
...         [a-zA-Z0-9_.]+
...         @
...         [a-zA-Z0-9-.]+?
...         \.
...         [a-zA-Z]{2,4}
...         (\.)?
...         ([a-zA-Z]{2,4})?
...         )'''
>>> re.findall(pattern3, msg, re.VERBOSE)
[('txt@deepstone.com.tw', '.', 'tw'), ('kkk@gmail.com', '', '')]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replying.I did try your suggestions: using [...]+? but it would got empty list and removing the dot would got the same result.

Comment: The `[...]` was intended to be a placeholder, not the literal thing you should type. Could you try my code for `pattern2` and `pattern3`? I'd be very surprised if they don't work.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for help! I misuderstand your previous reply. Yes, I tried your codes and it worked. Now, I know what the differences between your codes and mine. Much appreciated!!!